# How to disable multitouch 3 of 8 buttons? xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button

I have 8 buttons, I want to do so: When click on one of the buttons will be grayed out three and four are active. But it will be happening when I hold the button, but do not push it. If move finger on the button, and press it, all the buttons will be active. I tried using "exclusiveTouch" but it becomes inactive all 7 buttons.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    qsq.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq3.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq4.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq2_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq3_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    qsq4_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
}
```

When I click "qsq" then All the buttons are inactive. But I need qsq2, qsq3, qsq4 becomes inactive, and the other buttons are active.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried so far and explain what is not working

Comment: qsq.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq3.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq4.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq2_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq3_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;
qsq4_plr2.exclusiveTouch = YES;

When I click qsq then All the buttons are inactive
But I need qsq2,qsq3,qsq4 becomes inactive, and the other buttons are active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your design is a bit more complicated than the basic `UIView` properties can handle. Here's an example of the solution, only using 2 buttons.

Setup:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(disableButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(reenableButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside|UIControlEventTouchCancel];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(disableButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(reenableButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside|UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

And in the callbacks, you disable the buttons that need disabled:

```
-(void) disableButtons:(UIButton*)button {

    if (button == button1) {
        button2.enabled = FALSE;
    } else if (button == button2) {
        button1.enabled = FALSE;
    }
}

-(void) reenableButtons:(UIButton*)button {

    if (button == button1 || button == button2) {
        button1.enabled = TRUE;
        button2.enabled = TRUE;
    }
}
```